# Cannot Access Domain Pointing To Apache2 Server From Different Network

Tags: apache, server

I have a godaddy domain pointing to the static ip address of my linux machine running apache 2. The host for the A record on godaddy is `@` and the ip is my machine ip.

Visiting the website from a different device on the same network works perfectly, however i would like for it to be accessed on the web from any network.

The confs are listed below and comments are removed to make them a bit easier to read. Thanks! :)

**apache2.conf**

```
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**domain conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in a LAN, you need to configure a NAT on your modem/router pointing to the server running apache. Then you need to configure a firewall policy to allow traffic coming on port 80/443 on your router to let the connection pass.

In the end you need to configure your godaddy domain record to point to your public ip address so everyone on the internet will resolve your domain with your public ip and will be able to access your web-site.

NOTE: if you have a dynamic ip address, you have to use a dynamic dns provides such as ddns to automatically update your domain whenever your public ip changes.